# Suspicious argument in str.lstrip callpylint(bad-str-strip-call)

Tags: python, строки

Не могу разобраться почему VS выдает ошибку, подчеркивая str, хотя всё работает.

Код:

```
for line_content in list(text['content'].split('\n')):
     name = str(line_content).lstrip('my names')
```

Ошибка:

> Suspicious argument in str.lstrip callpylint(bad-str-strip-call)
> class str(o: object=...) str(object='') -> str str(bytes_or_buffer[,
> encoding[, errors]]) -> str
>
> Create a new string object from the given object. If encoding or
> errors is specified, then the object must expose a data buffer that
> will be decoded using the given encoding and error handler. Otherwise,
> returns the result of object.str() (if defined) or repr(object).
> encoding defaults to sys.getdefaultencoding(). errors defaults to
> 'strict'.

Не понимаю, что за a new string object нужно создавать. На разных форумах встречаются вопросы по данной ошибке, но применительно к себе не нашёл рецепта.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что тут нужно исправить?

Comment: ну так выведите на печать line_content в цикле перед name= - тогда будет понятно, что там за аргумент.

Comment: Вывод помог, но не содержимого, оно вот такого вида: 'name Jo', типа переменной, она оказалась <class 'str'>. Так, что просто переделал на
name = line_content.lstrip('my names')
Хотя, помню, что без преобразования в str, в процессе написания кода, не работало.
Спасибо за помощь!